# CheckBox Checked state inside gridview

Tags: asp.net, gridview

I have a simple gridview

```
            <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" DataKeyNames="OriginatorID" AutoGenerateColumns="False"
            AllowPaging="True" OnPageIndexChanging="GridView1_PageIndexChanging" PageSize="5"
            OnPreRender="GridView1_PreRender">
            <Columns>
                <asp:TemplateField>
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox1" runat="server" />
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
                <asp:BoundField DataField="Originator" HeaderText="Originator" />
            </Columns>
        </asp:GridView>
```

I'm calling following code inside `GridView1_PageIndexChanging` event

```
        foreach (GridViewRow item in GridView1.Rows)
        {
            try
            {
                if (item.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
                {
                    CheckBox chk = (CheckBox)(item.Cells[0].FindControl("CheckBox1"));

                    // chk.checked will access the checkbox state on button click event
                    if (chk.Checked)
                    {
                        //code if checked
                    }
                    else
                    {

                    }
                }

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw ex;
            }
        }
```

problem if I select a checkbox and select the next page on gridview it never execute the code inside

```
 if (chk.Checked)
```

even though I have checked the chekBoxes it's not get their state as checked.

why could this happen?

Comment: Have you debugged to see whether `chk` gets assigned to a control? Does `FindControl` returns a `CheckBox` ? I haven't checked but maybe the generated name for `CheckBox1` may not be *CheckBox1*. Try the `FindControl` with `CheckBox1.ClientID`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

Check Wheather you have put your code for binding data to GridView in

```
If (!IsPostBack)
{
     //Code for Binding Data to GridView 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

my fault.i haven't done the following

```
  if (!Page.IsPostBack)
            {

                Binddata();//Bind data to gridview
            }
```

previously Binddata() method was not inside

> if (!Page.IsPostBack)

which was causing the issue