# GridView does not update values on postback?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a gridview with some custom templates:

```
 <asp:GridView ID="gvGroups" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False"
     CssClass="table table-hover table-striped" GridLines="None" >
        <Columns>
            <asp:BoundField DataField="GroupDescription" HeaderText="Name" ReadOnly="True" 
                SortExpression="GroupDescription" />
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Administrator">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:CheckBox ID="cbAdmin" runat="server" 
                    Checked='<%# Boolean.Parse((Boolean)Eval("IsReadOnly") ? "True" : "False") ? false : true %>'/>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Remove">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:CheckBox ID="cbRemove" runat="server" />
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="ID" SortExpression="GroupID" Visible="False">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Label ID="lblID" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("GroupID") %>'></asp:Label>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
        </Columns>
    </asp:GridView>
```

I then have a button that I click and that is supposed to change group administration and remove groups that are checked.

Here is the button code:

```
  protected void btnSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            foreach (GridViewRow gvr in gvGroups.Rows)
            {
                CheckBox cbAdmin = (CheckBox)gvr.FindControl("cbAdmin");
                CheckBox cbRemove = (CheckBox)gvr.FindControl("cbRemove");
                Label lblID = (Label)gvr.FindControl("lblID");
                int id;
                bool idValid = int.TryParse(lblID.Text,out id);
                bool isReadOnly = !cbAdmin.Checked;


                if (idValid)
                {
                    Group g = SecurityManager.GetGroup(id);

                    if (g.IsReadOnly != isReadOnly)
                    {
                        bool updateSuccess = SecurityManager.ChangeGroupPermissions(id, isReadOnly);
                    }

                    if (cbRemove.Checked)
                    {
                        bool removeEmpSuccess = SecurityManager.RemoveEmployeesFromGroup(id);
                        bool removeSuccess = SecurityManager.RemoveGroup(id);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

I used the debugger and even when I uncheck admin on all groups, when I look at cbAdmin.Checked, it is still true, which is the same value it started with, thus nothing ever happens.

What could be the problem? Why am I not seeing the updated values on the button postback?

Thanks

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8936633/checkbox-checked-state-inside-gridview

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to call `GridView#DataBind()` within `if(!IsPostBack){ }`

Also you need to set AutoPostBack property of the textboxes to "true"

Comment: Now this works but I have to refresh after removing an item to see the change.

Comment: Multiple ways, my favorite: location.href='yourpage.aspx'

Comment: I am not sure I understand.

Comment: But how do I fix the refresh problem?

Comment: @Milo do you _want_ to refresh the page?

Answer (score 0):

I guess that you're databinding the `GridView` on postbacks. That will load the data from database again and prevent changes. So ue the `PostBack` property of the `Page`:

```
protected void Page_Load(Object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if(!IsPostBack)
    {
        DataBindGridView();
    }
}
```