# What's wrong with this GridView code C#?

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, gridview

I have a GridView with checkboxes. If I click in one checkbox I want to get the values in that row.
The problem is that chk (in C# code) never gets the value "true" so therefore the code never gets into the if-statement.

Thanks for your help. I've spent two nights at this problem now.

C#

```
    protected void btnChange_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string id= "";
        string name = "";

        foreach (GridViewRow row in GridView1.Rows)
        {
            CheckBox chk = (CheckBox)row.FindControl("myCheckBox");
            if (chk != null && chk.Checked)
            {
                id = row.Cells[1].Text;
                name = row.Cells[2].Text;
            }
        }          
    }
```

ASP.NET

```
   <div style="height:200px; width:450px; overflow:scroll;">
                            <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" GridLines="Horizontal" HeaderStyle-BackColor="#FFF8C6" HeaderStyle-ForeColor="Black" Height="200px" Width="450px">
                                <HeaderStyle HorizontalAlign="Left" />
                                <Columns>
                                    <asp:TemplateField>
                                        <ItemTemplate>
                                            <asp:CheckBox ID="myCheckBox" runat="server" />
                                        </ItemTemplate>
                                    </asp:TemplateField>
                                </Columns>
                            </asp:GridView>
                        </div>
```

Comment: Is `chk` null or `chk.Checked` always false?  Also, are you **positive** that your JavaScript function isn't setting it to false?

Comment: I have removed JS (see ASP.NET code). chk is always false.

Comment: Did you actually step through the code in a debugger or are you assuming it's always false?

Comment: I also thought the JavaScript might do something to the code, so therefore I removed the JS call from ASP.NET code. I have also removed it here.

Comment: @Rick S I have stepped through the code to find that Checked is always false

Answer (score 0):

Problem is solved!
I found this solution:

Try this:

Check Wheather you have put your code for binding data to GridView in

```
If (!IsPostBack)
{
     //Code for Binding Data to GridView 
}
```

from this link:[CheckBox Checked state inside gridview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8936633/checkbox-checked-state-inside-gridview?rq=1)